# Android Admob without Google Play

Tags: android, admob

I couldn't find anything on the web. Is there a way to use the AdMob SDK to monetize my app without having the app in the Google Play store.

Anybody of you who may know?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 7):

You do not need to distribute your app through Google Play in order to use AdMob SDK. Regardless of the distribution method, it will work as long as it's correctly configured.

Google Play is just a way to distribute your apps.

Comment: Okay thanks. I thought there is a connection between them, that ads will only work if I'm going to distribute the app over the Google appstore.

Answer (score -2):

you can use admob in testmode like:

```
request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
```

or

```
request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
```

Taken from https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/46289-how-to-use-admob-in-test-mode/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR); or request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);