# Admob integration without publishing app

Tags: android, admob

my question is simple - can I use Admob ads in android app without publishing it in google play? Thanks for anyone help.

Comment: duplicated check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050071/android-admob-without-google-play/)

Answer (score 2):

***Yes***, you can use it without publishing your app on playstore.There is no such condition that your app needs to be published on Playstore.

Answer (score 1):

You should choose the option which says add your app manually. After publishing your app you can link it after 48 hours. (Admob refreshes apps every 48 hours.)