# Admob ads in Android app

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am developing an app and I'll monetize it using Google's Admob ads. However I don't currently have a Google Play Store developer account. I'll distribute this app by uploading it to my own website or by providing a download link to Google Drive.

Will Admob work with my being installed outside of PlayStore? Will this affect revenue generated by Admob?

Comment: This has been asked already. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050071/android-admob-without-google-play, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662563/can-i-use-admob-without-uploading-at-playstore, ... Vote for close! And of course it will affect your revenue since the market you're targeting is much smaller without Google Play.

Comment: Admob uses Google Play Store library which requires Google Play Store APK installed on users phone. If you deploy your app outside of the Google Play store, it is not guaranteed that your user's devices will have the Google Play services APK installed. It will result in a no-op and an error being logged, which may cause ads not to serve to those devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will Admob work with my being installed outside of PlayStore? Will this affect revenue generated by Admob?

-> Yes it will affect

> but make sure the apk you put on your website should not be debug
>   build, it should be signed apk.

Answer (score 0):

> Will Admob work with my being installed outside of PlayStore?

Yes. The Mobile Ads SDK will work without Google Play services installed on the user's device, and in apps that aren't on the Play store.

> Will this affect revenue generated by Admob?

This is a guess, so don't hold me to it (I haven't tried it personally), but I don't think there's anything intrinsic to the SDK that would cause your revenue to go down significantly. It's possible that low numbers of installs might result from not being in the Play store, though.